# Activerecord group by count and user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models with has_many associations.

```
User :has_many foos
Foo :belongs_to user
```

Foo.joins(:user)

I want to have a group by on Foo, where it returns with count and user_id.
Means I want to know how many 'foos' with 'user_id'.

Eg:

```
user_id foos_count 
-------------
1     31
2     52
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the query to meet the need :

```
Foo.group(:user_id).count
```